# Inconsistent behaviour of `cut`: Different intervals with same number and same displayed cut points

Tags: r, formatting, binning, discretization

I encountered the following inconsistent behaviour of `cut` which gives me a headache:

```
x <- 0.2316
cut(x, c(0, 0.2315, 10)) #gives 0.232 as cutpoint and choses second interval
## [1] (0.232,10]
## Levels: (0,0.232] (0.232,10]
cut(x, c(0, 0.232, 10)) #choses first interval when taking the same cutpoint it just gave (0.232)
## [1] (0,0.232]
## Levels: (0,0.232] (0.232,10]
```

The problem is that `cut` seems to chose the interval before formatting (rounding) the cut points. This leads to the inconsistent behaviour in the example that it chooses the second interval but would have chosen the first interval according to the given cut point (which can be seen in the last line).

This is a problem for me because I have two functions in my package: One is calculating the cut points and the second is determining the right intervals where to put new data points. In the example above the same data point is put into the second interval in the first function but into the first interval in the second function - displaying the exact same cut points! That can lead to some strange behaviour in my package!

**My question**
Is this a known issue? And if yes are there any workarounds? Thank you

**Edit**
I know that you can change the number of decimal places with `dig.lab` yet the same problem would occur if you had cut points with more decimal places. The above example is just a demonstration of a more general problem!

Comment: Do you want more digits for the cutpoints? That would be `cut(x, c(0, 0.2315, 10), dig.lab = 4)`.

Comment: @lukeA: I know, yet the same problem would occur one decimal place further down when you had a number with more decimal places as the cutpoint. The above is just an illustrative example!

Comment: @lukeA: Please see my edit.

Comment: As lukeA points out, `cut` is using the correct point for partitioning. However, the print out is rounding. One fix for this if you are building functions for other users is to include a "dig.labs" argument in your function that will allow the user to choose the precision of the printed intervals.

Comment: @lmo: Thank you. Unfortunately this would not solve my problem because the cutpoints that are printed are used in my function No. 2 to chose the right interval and then again the wrong ones will be chosen in those unfortunate cases (see also my edit).

Comment: Since you are setting the cutpoints, can you grab these separately?

Comment: @RichardTelford: Yes, I think I found a way myself by having a look at the source code of `cut.default` - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a look at the source code of `cut.default` and I think one workaround would be to apply the same formatting that is applied on the printout on the `breaks` before calling the `cut` function:

```
breaks <- as.numeric(formatC(0 + c(0, 0.2315, 10), digits = 3, width = 1L))
cut(x, breaks = breaks)
## [1] (0,0.232]
## Levels: (0,0.232] (0.232,10]
```

Then at least everything is consistent (so in this case the first interval is chosen in both cases).

Yet this only works in cases where you set the cut points explicitly!